# How to increase size of logo in header on Wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've added a logo to the header of my website `www.theestablishmenthairdressing.com` however it comes out very small (logo in the top-left).

I can see by inspecting the code in `Safari` that it looks like there is a restriction to the size of the logo built into the theme:

```
<h1 class="header-logo">
   <a href="http://www.theestablishmenthairdressing.com/" rel="home">
      <img class="" width="50" height="50" src="//www.theestablishmenthairdressing.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Establishment-LOGO-header.png" alt="The Establishment Hairdressing" />                        
   </a>
</h1>
```

However it's not clear to me how to change this. I've tried adding 
**CSS**

```
h1.header-logo {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

To the child theme's style.css however this did not make a difference.

Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the file to the child theme folder in which this code is probably `header.php` and remove `width="50" height="50"` from the `img` tag. Now you can do your changes in `style.css`.

Comment: I located the php file (was actually in a "headers" folder in the parent theme as there are several header variations). I copied the file over to the child theme however did not over-ride the parent theme so just ended up making a backup of the parent php file and editing it directly, seemed to work fine. Thanks for your answer :).

Answer (score 1):

you should use like below.

```
    h1.header-logo img {
        width: 200px !important;
    }
```

or

```
h1.header-logo>a>img {
        width: 200px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the width and height attributes of the image tag:

```
<img class="" src="//www.theestablishmenthairdressing.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Establishment-LOGO-header.png" alt="The Establishment Hairdressing">
```

It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://wpdemos.themezaa.com/pofo/documentation/knowledgebase/logo-typography-and-colors/change-logo-size/

**Code for header logo**

```
header a.logo-light img{ max-height: 26px;}
```

**Code for sticky header logo**

```
header a.logo-dark img {max-height: 26px;}
```

**Code for footer logo**

```
.footer-logo { max-height: 26px; }
```

**Code for Hamburger logo**

```
.hamburger-logo img { max-height: 46px; }
```